# "Spontaneous Immortalization"

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture

HaCaT keratinocytes are described as "spontaneously immortalized "(see paper below) due to aneuploidy or chromosomal alteration.
From the paper I get that this is a literal term, that the cells just continued growing (?) in vitro and never went into senescence without any "human-induced" transformation.
Is this a common procedure for cell immortalization or a rather rare example?

[http://jcb.rupress.org/content/106/3/761.long][1]

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you define it. Many early cell lines (as well as some modern ones) were derived from tumors. Tumors are spontaneously immortalized cells which became immortalized *in vivo*. If you're asking how often researchers collect primary cells (non immortalized) and grow them with the hopes they will become immortal the answer is pretty much never.